# Next.js server actions - eslint errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, eslint

Getting eslint errors writing a simple server component with server action:

```
// /app/search/page.tsx

export default function Search() {

  async function updateResults(formData: FormData) {
    "use server";
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 150));
    console.log("input value => ", formData.get("me"));
    revalidatePath("/search");
  }

 return (
    <>
      <form action={updateResults}>  {/* eslint errors here */}
        <input name="me" type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

Get a couple eslint errors on the `<form action={updateResults}>`

- `JSX props should not use functions eslint(react/jsx-no-bind)`
- `Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises)`

What am I doing wrong? Can we call server actions from RSC or should the form be a client component only?

I'm on next 14 with eslint 8.36

My `package.json`:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@next/third-parties": "^14.0.4",
    "i18next": "^23.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "^14.0.3",
    "next-i18next": "^15.0.0",
    "next-intl": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^14.0.0",
    "server-only": "^0.0.1",
    "sharp": "^0.33.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ianvs/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-designs": "^7.0.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.1.0",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.1.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.1.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest-axe": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.55.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.55.0",
    "eslint": "^8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-mycustomconfig": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.2.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.12",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.11.0",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-axe": "^7.0.0",
    "jest-cli": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^8.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "sass": "^1.59.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "storybook": "^7.1.0",
    "storybook-react-i18next": "^2.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.0"
  }
```

`eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    "plugin:storybook/recommended",
    // Disable ESLint code formatting rules which conflict with Prettier
    "prettier",
    // `next` should be extended last according to their docs
    // https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint
    "next/core-web-vitals",
  ],
  rules: {
    // Next.js <Image> component is useful for optimizing images, but also requires additional
    // dependencies to work in standalone mode. It may be overkill for most projects at
    // Which aren't image heavy.
    "@next/next/no-img-element": "off",
  },
  // Additional lint rules. These get layered onto the top-level rules.
  overrides: [
    // Lint config specific to Test files
    {
      files: ["tests/**"],
      plugins: ["jest"],
      extends: [
        "plugin:jest/recommended",
        "plugin:jest-dom/recommended",
        "plugin:testing-library/react",
      ],
    },
    // Lint config specific to TypeScript files
    {
      files: "**/*.+(ts|tsx)",
      parserOptions: {
        // These paths need defined to support rules that require type information
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
        project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
      },
      extends: [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        // Disable vanilla ESLint rules that conflict with those in @typescript-eslint
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        // Rules that specifically require type information
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
      ],
      plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
      rules: {
        // Prevent dead code accumulation
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
        // The usage of `any` defeats the purpose of typescript. Consider using `unknown` type instead instead.
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
      },
    },
  ],
  settings: {
    // Support projects where Next.js isn't installed in the root directory (such as a monorepo)
    next: {
      rootDir: __dirname,
    },
  },
};
```

I didn't really follow the next 14 eslint setup docs so there may be issues there.

Comment: Can you show your package.json and your eslintrc file?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar added those files

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong with server actions. Just disable the `@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises` as this how actions should be used.

Comment: Yep that works as expected - curious if there's any package updates or config that might fix it if anyone knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using correctly server actions. You just have to disable the ESLint rule added by one of the `extends` in the `overrides` part of your `.eslintrc.js`, which makes sense in most scenarios but didn't predict server actions in React:

```js
{
  files: "**/*.+(ts|tsx)",
  // ...
  rules: {
    //...
    "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": "off",
  },
}
```